# When people brag about their abilities and belittle their opponents before a battle, competition, etc

Tags: word-request

I'm writing an article about a myth in which two epic heroes facing each other before a single combat. The part I'm at now is when the two heroes start bragging about their abilities and things they've accomplished while at the same time they try to belittle their  opponent by saying things like, "now tell me boy, you think you can handle a man?" or "before you were born I had been the champion of the champions." I think this part of the battle was mainly to diminish the opponent's self-confidence.

The modern version of this can be seen when let's say you want to have street car racing and start saying things like, "let's see how fast you can be on that wreck."

My questions are simply about describing this activity that people do before a competition, but since I provided two contexts, (one out of need, and the other out of curiosity), probably two words with a formal and informal register would be excellent. However, a neutral word is good enough. My sentences are:

1. > The heroes started [verb]ing.
2. > The racers were [verb]ing for a few minutes before going down the street at full throttle.

Thanks.

Comment: I searched for "individual [haka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haka)" but it does seem to require a group, and may be as much about a display as the words uttered. It might give you some ideas.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I kept looking for things that I've found in your comment and the answers (that I'm thankful for) and came across the word [_flyting_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyting) which led me to [flite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flite) also the word [depreciate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/depreciate). Do you think these verbs fit the first context? As in _the heroes depreciated\flited eachother for a while_.

Comment: I don't think flite or depreciate (perhaps you meant [deprecate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deprecate)) are strong enough words, and flite would not be understood by many readers. I'm wondering about [face off](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/face%20off).

Comment: Face off As in a hockey game. It's a good word probably implying the readiness of opponents for a good fight but it doesn't imply belittling or braging. Deprecate as you proposed is a better candidate. Thank you Andrew Morton. I'm gona wait for a possible better option. I'll have a day to deliver my article BTW :)

Comment: Along with *flyting* is *bragging* or *the bragging ritual*. Another interesting related word is *beot*.

Comment: "Face off" isn't bad.  "The two faced off before the battle and traded barbs." might be what you want.

Comment: "Banter" seems like a reasonable word, though it doesn't have all of the meanings you might intend.  It can be a more neutral word with less negative connotations.

Comment: @Damkerng T: But **beot** is not a ModE word.

Comment: @Yuri You will not do better than J.R.'s answer here. I was about to add **talking smack,** which is a close second imo.

Comment: @P. E. Dant The word perfectly bears the meaning I want though it's informal. Do you think it would be fine to include it in this rather formal context?

Comment: @Andrew I like your suggestion. Maybe I need to extend my sentence to make my meaning.

Comment: @Yuri No, certainly not. _Taunt_ is the best you have so far, I think, although its impact has degraded somewhat (to some audiences) due to its use in the rules of the American NFL.  I'm not so sure English provides exactly the word you want. The archaic _Beot_ is close, but you would need to supply a footnote. "Taunt and vilify" or "Taunt and belittle" together might work.

Comment: @Yuri "face off" is optional but "trade barbs" sounds good for your mythological context. as it evokes an image of the two heroes throwing hooked spears at each other.

Comment: [What is a less vulgar, but informal phrase for “talk a lot of s***”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319415/what-is-a-less-vulgar-but-informal-phrase-for-talk-a-lot-of-s)

Comment: Too late for deadline, and not a verb (hence only a comment), but braggadocio is the term for this behaviour.  'Induging in braggadocio' might work?

Comment: @mcalex never late to learn a new word :) yea it's a good word since it is _speaking of yourself in **superlatives** in an **annoying** way_. I had a search and I think it's actually a good choice esp. in such a mythical context. I liked it.

Comment: "English does not provide the word he wants?" Chest thumping and saber rattling, come to mind.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

See synonyms for "taunt": *mock, belittle, deride, insult, derogate, disparage, deprecate, ridicule, jeer, put down, make fun of*, as well as slang terms like *disrespect, trash, or hate on*.

"Taunt" is the verb closest to your meaning, but not necessarily the one you want to use since it doesn't automatically mean "insult".  "Trash" is a good slang term in a contemporary context, but not necessarily when talking about mythical or historical figures since it would be a modern anachronism.

Comment: +1 I didn't know taunt can be used in this type of contexts. always thought it's used to describe children being mean. I came across this [_The hero could not resist a taunt. “Just to set the record straight, the name’s Odysseus,” he called across the water_](http://www.greekmyths-greekmythology.com/odysseus-and-cyclops-myth/)

Comment: Relevant to current events, ["Watch Clinton Taunt Trump for His Unreleased Tax Returns" (Fortune.com)](http://fortune.com/video/2016/09/26/presidential-debate-unreleased-tax-return/)

Comment: @Yuri: Taunt has the exact meaning of the context you want. It means saying things to make your opponent angry. It could be bragging (look what I did!) or it could be saying something mean (your mom!). When people say children "taunt" it means they're picking a fight. Another synonym for "taunt" that fits the context is "fighting words" (which incidentally is the legal term for it and is not protected by the 1st amendment in the US)

Comment: @slebetman You'd go like, _the heroes taunted eachother for a while_? Or _the heroes traded taunts for a while_ How do you think I would make better sense?

Comment: @Yuri: Either would work. It's a matter of taste I guess. Somehow as a verb "taunted" sounds to me more childish than "trading taunts" but that's just my bias

Comment: @Yuri Also, depending on the style you want to achieve, "traded fighting words" sounds awesome

Comment: @slebetman Cartment would go _Sweeeet_ :)

Comment: +1 for the bit about "talking trash" (or smack, etc.) likely being inappropriate for the OP's stated purpose.  I would never describe the banter between two epic heroes as "trash talk" -- it seems flippant and does not convey the "weight" that such a monumental confrontation should carry.

Comment: Indeed, a good taunt is, dare I say, the [Holy Grail](https://youtu.be/QSo0duY7-9s) of insults.

Answer (score 45):

In the U.S., a good term for this is ***trash talking***. The term [**trash talk**](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+of+trash+talking) can be used as a noun or a verb, and it can refer to good natured jabs between friends, or ugly taunts at the professional level.

The term is usually used in sports, but is occasionally used in realms such as politics as well.

It's definitely more on the informal register. (For a more formal word, see the synonyms listed by Andrew in his answer.)

Comment: +1 but **talking smack,** of similar provenance, is a widely-employed alternative and perhaps a bit more _au courant._

Comment: Yup.  I'd say "trash talk" is more low-brow and relatable than "taunt"..which is not a word that the people doing said talking would use themselves to describe what they were doing.

Comment: Isn't trash talking just talking your oppent down, without embiggening your own prowess?

Comment: @Mawg - I think some of the best trash talk incorporates a little bit of both, like when [Larry Bird](http://www.foxsports.com/nba/story/boston-celtics-larry-bird-trash-talking-genius-031215) asked, "Which one of you is coming in second place?" right before the NBA 3-point shooting contest.

Comment: Sounds perfectly cromulent to me

Comment: A now-obsolete adverb for such behaviour that used to be appropriate here is *bigly*. This has been amusing me of late for topical reasons.

Comment: @Mawg i think not. The album _I'm the Greatest_ helped establish Muhammed Ali  Clay's reputation as an eloquently poetic ["trash talker"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_the_Greatest_(Cassius_Clay_album)) in which he boasts about himself and downplays his opponents.

Answer (score 10):

Somewhat more formal:

> **hector** (hĕkˈtər)► v.  To intimidate or dominate in a blustering way. -[wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/hector)

Comment: +1 talk to (someone) in a bullying way. I'm not really sure I can use that but thanks it has a similar connotation in other contexts.

Answer (score 7):

I find that "chest-beating" (or "chest-thumping") works well here.  Depending on the context, it might also be "ritual chest-beating".  Of course the phrase is lent from the behavior of great apes.

Now that's generally only a behavior you see with male apes (and they have the better-suited anatomy for it) but, uhm, the behavior you describe is really observable a whole lot more often with male humans as well.

Answer (score 7):

One you probably don't want to use because I don't think it's widespread outside cricket, but I mention it out of interest, is Sledging.

> Sledging is a term used in cricket to describe the practice whereby
>   some players seek to gain an advantage by insulting or verbally
>   intimidating the opposing player.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sledging_(cricket)

Answer (score 6):

One option I haven't seen yet is [*Boasting.*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/boast)

Unlike the other terms I've seen mentioned, Boasting is speaking very highly of yourself and implying that you're superior to your opponents, instead of simply saying your opponents are inferior. As such, it's considered slightly more positive & polite than trying to belittle your opposition.

Since your first example was about Heroes, I believe Boasting is a better fit.

Answer (score 4):

US presidential debates are excellent examples. They belittle each other but there are rules. It's almost like a show. Obviously they won't physically fight, but the concept is the same.

The word you are looking for is very environment based. I would recommend 'taunt', 'berate', 'degrade' or 'belittle' versus slang terms. You could say Hector was 'dissing' Patroclus, but it doesnt have the same effect. Maybe in something like Romeo + Juliet it would

Comment: +1 thanks for providing more contexts in which the word can be used.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of heroes, the phrase **verbal jousting** might be appropriate.  It means to have a battle of words, a verbal back and forth between individuals to see who can come out on top, and generally suggests an egotistic and sporting motive.

*Verbal jousting* is evocative of medieval combat and its inherent sense of pride and honor.

> "As soon as the banners fell and their eyes met, the heroes began their traditional bout of verbal jousting."
>
> "The smack talk went on all night, a verbal joust of epic proportions."
>
> "In general, English comedians are fond of quick wit and verbal jousting."

Hope this helps!  It's a fun phrase!

Comment: +1 Mentioning a  [reference](http://definithing.com/verbal-jousting/) would be excellent also how to fit the word in OP's sentence is quite helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Try "posturing" It's a little more generic, includes ideas like boasting, posing, etc.

Comment: You posture to make an impression or gain an advantage. But isn't it used with _as_ as in _they postured as Democrates to win the favor of some States_? Also I get the impression of fraud in it. Something like _passing oneself off_. Am I right? How do you suggest writing the sentence with _posture_?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was taunt, but I think a better word is **[harangue](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/harangue)** since it can include both boasting and taunting. I do have to admit though that the word has lost popularity over time. But it is still sufficiently current to be known, and does not seem out of place when talking of historical events.

> verb: to address (a person or crowd) in an angry, vehement, or
>   forcefully persuasive way

The word can also be used as a noun.

Examples:

> The heroes began their **haranguing**.

(from [story about Kit Carson](http://www.elpalacio.org/placeseries/winter07KitCarson.pdf))

> ...the exhausted mail party was pursued by 150 hostile Indians. Carson
>   guided his companions into a copse of stunted trees, where they tied
>   their mules, then he arranged them in a skirmishers’ line. He next
>   stepped forward, fully exposed, and began to **harangue** the enemy in
>   their own language. Brewerton wrote, “Carson’s whole demeanor was now
>   so entirely changed that he looked like a different man. His eyes
>   fairly flashed, and his rifle was grasped with all the energy of an
>   iron will.” And the lieutenant added that Carson knew “boldness alone
>   could save us.”

Answer (score 0):

In the context of opponents, you could try the phrase "Provocation" which stems from the verb "Provocate" meaning to provoke something. This would be a bad-natured way of trying to get your enemy to fight. It has an angry connotation to it. 
An example of a good phrase would be "exaggerated". The opponents want to show off to each other who has the better skills to fight.

Sources: www.thesaurus.com for ideas of other synonym relations.

Hope this helped with some ideas.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Branden. That's an interesting opinion, but we prefer opinions to be backed up by references- for example, a link to a definition of 'provocate' with this meaning.

Answer (score -1):

One word you may try is "bantering." The dictionary definition denotes exchanging belittling remarks in a teasing or good-natured way, as between friends. However, common usage today doesn't necessarily include the connotation of playfulness or good nature.

Comment: Thank you although I can't confirm what you claim. I personally heard _banter_ in the sense of _joshing someone_. Others might want to post comments here and help me with it.

Comment: "belittling remarks in a teasing or good-natured way, as between friends" is exactly NOT what OP wanted. It is before a combat, presumably to death, between (mortal) enemies.